# Faster queries from Google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-sheets, google-fusion-tables

I have a Google spreadsheet with 7000 rows and 12 columns. I want to fetch the data with a basic AJAX query.

```
url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/"+key+"/od6/public/basic?alt=json-in-script&callback=?";
$.getJSON(url, function(resp) {  
    console.log(resp)
});
```

Problem is this query takes me more than 8 second to do. However, if I upload the data to Google Fusion Tables I retrieve the data within a second with a corresponding AJAX query.

[image]

The size of the query from Google Spreadsheet puzzles me. 19MB? Is there any way get data from a big spreadsheet with reasonable efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. As far as I can tell, you're doing it right.